# Struggling with interface like approach in Haskell

Tags: haskell, interface

I have a problem understanding how to deal with interfaces like approach in Haskell. If thinking about it in OOP terms then I would like to have different objects implementing the same interface (just couple of methods) and keep track of some internal state.

I started with some typeclass

```
class FileTransformer where
    doThis :: a -> b -> c
    doThat :: d -> e -> f
```

And though that if I would create different data types like

```
data FirstThingy = FirstThingy { internalState :: STRef s Int } -- simplified
data SecondThingy = SecondThingy { differentState :: STRef s Word8 } -- simplified

instance FileTransformer FirstThingy where
    doThis = ... -- does some stuff with internal state also
    doThat = ... -- does some stuff with internal state also

-- implementation of doThis and doThat is different from the above one
instance FileTransformer SecondThingy where
    doThis = ... -- does some stuff with internal state also
    doThat = ... -- does some stuff with internal state also
```

And then I though it would be enough to do something like this:

```
firstThingy = FirstThingy someInitialState
secondThingy = SecondThingy someOtherInitialState

loadFileTransformer :: FileTransformer ft => FileHeader -> ft
loadFileTransformer header = if simple header then firstThingy else secondThingy
```

But well, as you might have already guessed this does not work...

So, the question is what would be the approach in Haskell that will allow me to select a different file transformer based on some particular needs? Each transformer must have 2 methods (but with different implementations) and can also have some internal state (which is very different when compared to each other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using an ADT to represent your `Thingy`s, rather than two seperate types:

```
data Thingy = FirstThingy (STRef s Int) | SecondThingy (STRef s Word8)
```

Then you can pattern match on `Thingy`:

```
doThis :: Thingy -> a -> b -> c
doThis (FirstThingy st) = ...
doThis (SecondThingy st) = ...
```

and similarly with `doThat`. Then your last code block would look like this:

```
firstThingy = FirstThingy someInitialState
secondThingy = SecondThingy someOtherInitialState

loadFileTransformer :: FileHeader -> Thingy
loadFileTransformer header
    | simple header = firstThingy
    | otherwise = secondThingy
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I knew it would turn out to be something quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to *create an object* with internal state that represents the different file transformations, you probably want to just *call a function* with suitable arguments.

Without seeing how your transformers are to be used, it's difficult to say exactly how best to structure this. But if, say, you have a `doTheStuff` function that wants to take a "transformer object" as input, why not make it just take the two "methods" as arguments, along with the initial state value?

```
doTheStuff :: state -> (state -> a -> b -> c) -> (state -> d -> e -> f) -> ...
```